# ROS site downs very often or it is just me?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This might not involve with technical issue. However, I have a lot of problem in getting in the ROS website may be 3 times already in this month. Is it just me? or everyone encounter this problem?

I ask this because if it's just me, I then can find the cause and solve the problem myself.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12055/ros-site-downs-very-often-or-it-is-just-me?/) by [ParNurZeal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1210/parnurzeal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2011-11-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-23**:
While the recent outages have been annoying, they are not common. That was the first lengthy down time I can recall in several years. The wiki mirrors (see below) were created as an immediate response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There were some technical problems (a power outage, among others) recently. For these cases there are read-only mirrors of the wiki:

- http://ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/roswiki/
- http://ros.jsk.imi.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/roswiki/
- http://mirror.umd.edu/roswiki/
- ...and more at http://www.ros.org/wiki/Mirrors

Best bookmark them now!

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2011-11-22**:
Not that I know, but maybe it's halfway working through Google cache.

**Comment by [ParNurZeal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1210/parnurzeal/) on 2011-11-22**:
How about answer.ros.org? Is there an up-to-date for the forum?

**Comment by [ParNurZeal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1210/parnurzeal/) on 2011-11-22**:
This helps me a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was done for me two some days ago (for a long time). I usually use this web for this type of things (to check if it's me or not):
http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/

---

Originally posted by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) with karma: 385 on 2011-11-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2012-03-01**:
interesting~